# how to convert string to lots of list,

Tags: java, list, netbeans, arraylist

how do i seperate a string to use,
extract of code

```
JTextField stockNo = new JTextField(7);
JTextField quantity = new JTextField(7);
TextArea information = new TextArea(5, 50);
JButton purchaseBtn = new JButton("Purchase");
purchaseBtn.addActionListener(this);
//set up gui ect
String key = stockNo.getText();
String quantityTxt = quantity.getText();
String info = "\n\nName: " + StockData.getName(key) + 
                    "\nPrice: £" + (StockData.getPrice(key)) + 
                    "\nNumber in stock: " + StockData.getQuantity(key) +
                    "\nNumber to buy: " + quantityTxt;
information.append(info);
```

when user clicks purchaseBtn, the before information should stay therefor the `.append`, what i need is somehow to extract the info from the information text area, and use it to do calculation, someone told me arraylist but have no idea.

eg

```
 //in text area
Name: shirt //user inputed 1 for key
Price: £5.00
Number in stock: 15
Number to buy 7 // user inputed 7 for quantity

Name: socks //user inputed 2 for key
Price: £2.50
Number in stock: 4
Number to buy 1 // user inputed 7 for quantity

Name: trouser //user inputed 3 for key
Price: £24.00
Number in stock: 19
Number to buy 4 // user inputed 7 for quantity
```

i need to get it to save the key and quantity for each row, so i can do things with it later, and be able to say `int totalcost = //the price of all of them added together in our example £31.50`,

Comment: What's the question? We're not going to write the code for you. What specific part are you having trouble with?

Comment: None of your question is intelligible.

Answer (score 0):

You are operating in a OO language.  All you information should be managed within Objects, that's the point.

Use a `JList` instead of `JTextArea`.

Place your purchase information in a `Purchase` object which carries all the information you require, such as `name`, `price,`inStock`and`toBuy`.

You can then use a `ListCellRenderer` to render the individual elements of the `Purchase` object as needed.

This will make it significantly easier to manage.

See [How to use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more information

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e8cwysszjb5544n/puchaseitem.zip?m code you please look at it, i cant join it together,